# How to make 5 threads read and write array concurrently

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm having an attempt at the famous producer-consumer problem in c++ and I have came up with an implementation like this...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctime>

void *consumeThread(void *i);
void *produceThread(void *i);

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
//Bucket size
#define Bucket_size 10

int buckets[Bucket_size];
pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t consume_now, produce_now;

time_t timer;

int o = 0;
int p = 0;

int main()
{
    int i[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    pthread_t consumer[5];
    pthread_t producer[5];

    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, nullptr);
    pthread_cond_init(&consume_now, nullptr);
    pthread_cond_init(&produce_now, nullptr);

    timer = time(nullptr) + 10;

    srand(time(nullptr));
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        pthread_create(&producer[x], nullptr, &produceThread, &i[x]);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        pthread_create(&consumer[x], nullptr, &consumeThread, &i[x]);
    }

    pthread_cond_signal(&produce_now);

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        pthread_join(producer[x], nullptr);
        pthread_join(consumer[x], nullptr);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&consume_now);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&produce_now);

    return 0;
}

void *consumeThread(void *i)
{

    bool quit = false;

    while (!quit)
    {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        pthread_cond_wait(&consume_now, &lock);

        printf("thread %d consuming element at array[%d] : the element is %d \n", *((int *)i), o, buckets[o]);
        buckets[o] = 0;
        p++;
        printArray();
        usleep(100000);

        pthread_cond_signal(&produce_now);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

        quit = time(nullptr) > timer;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void *produceThread(void *i)
{

    int a = 0;
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {

        o = p % 10;
        buckets[o] = (rand() % 20) + 1;
        printf("thread %d adding element in array[%d] : the element is %d \n", *((int *)i), o, buckets[o]);
        a++;
        printArray();
        usleep(100000);

        quit = time(nullptr) > timer;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

currently this solution has 5 producer threads and 5 consumer threads, however it only lets 1 thread produce and 1 thread consume at a time, is there a way to make 5 of the producer and consumer threads work concurrently?

Example output from the program:
thread 1 adding element in array[0] : the element is 6
[6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: This is very C-like, producer-consumer design only requires thread-safe queue with optionally blocking `T pop()`. Create a `Queue` class first, then the worker threads become  very easy and unaware of multi-threading. Concentrating multi-threaded code into as few places is possible is usually best.

Comment: Why not use C++ threads?

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is that you are treating *condition variables* as if they have memory.   In your *main()*, you *pthread_cond_signal()*, but at that point, you have no idea if any of your threads are waiting upon that condition.   Since condition variables do not have *memory*, your *signal* may well be lost.

Your second problem is that *o* is effectively protected by the condition; since each consumer uses it; and each producer modifies it, you can neither permit multiple producers or consumers to execute concurrently.

Your desired solution amounts to a queue which you inject *o*'s into from the producers; and collect them in the consumers.  That way, your concurrency is gated by your ability to produce *o*'s.